# "Errors while handling" kernel packages after dist-upgrade

Tags: apt, upgrade, kernel

I did an apt-get dist-upgrade, now everytime I do something using apt-get, e.g. installing something, it gives me that there are errors while handling the following packages:

```
linux-image-extra-3.13.0-35-generic
linux-image-generic
linux-generic
```

My system still works correctly, but is this normal? And what should I do? Should I do anything? Have I done the wrong thing by doing a dist-upgrade? (Beginner-like instructions please, I'm not an expert. Using Xubuntu 14.04.) Here is the full output of dist-upgrade, as someone asked for it:

```
Pakketlijsten worden ingelezen... Klaar
Boom van vereisten wordt opgebouwd       
De status informatie wordt gelezen... Klaar
Opwaardering wordt doorgerekend... Klaar
De volgende pakketten zullen opgewaardeerd worden:
  google-chrome-beta openjdk-7-jre openjdk-7-jre-headless
3 pakketten opgewaardeerd, 0 pakketten nieuw geïnstalleerd, 0 te verwijderen en 0 niet opgewaardeerd.
3 pakketten niet volledig geïnstalleerd of verwijderd.
Er moeten 88,8 MB aan archieven opgehaald worden.
Door deze operatie zal er 480 kB extra schijfruimte gebruikt worden.
Wilt u doorgaan? [J/n] j
Ophalen:1 http://be.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main openjdk-7-jre amd64 7u65-2.5.1-4ubuntu1~0.14.04.1 [183 kB]
Ophalen:2 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable/main google-chrome-beta amd64 37.0.2062.94-1 [49,2 MB]
Ophalen:3 http://be.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main openjdk-7-jre-headless amd64 7u65-2.5.1-4ubuntu1~0.14.04.1 [39,5 MB]
88,8 MB opgehaald in 15s (5.793 kB/s)                                          
(Database inlezen ... 386009 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../google-chrome-beta_37.0.2062.94-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking google-chrome-beta (37.0.2062.94-1) over (37.0.2062.76-1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../openjdk-7-jre_7u65-2.5.1-4ubuntu1~0.14.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking openjdk-7-jre:amd64 (7u65-2.5.1-4ubuntu1~0.14.04.1) over (7u55-2.4.7-1ubuntu1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../openjdk-7-jre-headless_7u65-2.5.1-4ubuntu1~0.14.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking openjdk-7-jre-headless:amd64 (7u65-2.5.1-4ubuntu1~0.14.04.1) over (7u55-2.4.7-1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.6.7.1-1) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.10.1-0ubuntu2) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.22-1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon (0.5.1+14.04.20140409-0ubuntu1) ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf-2.index...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.54ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.13-1) ...
Instellen van linux-image-extra-3.13.0-35-generic (3.13.0-35.62) ...
Running depmod.
update-initramfs: deferring update (hook will be called later)
initrd.img(/boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-35-generic
) points to /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-35-generic
 (/boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-35-generic) -- doing nothing at /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-extra-3.13.0-35-generic.postinst line 491.
vmlinuz(/boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-35-generic
) points to /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-35-generic
 (/boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-35-generic) -- doing nothing at /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-extra-3.13.0-35-generic.postinst line 491.
Examining /etc/kernel/postinst.d.
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 3.13.0-35-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-35-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 3.13.0-35-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-35-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-35-generic

gzip: stdout: No space left on device
E: mkinitramfs failure cpio 141 gzip 1
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-35-generic with 1.
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools exited with return code 1
Failed to process /etc/kernel/postinst.d at /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-extra-3.13.0-35-generic.postinst line 1025.
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-extra-3.13.0-35-generic (--configure):
 subproces installed post-installation script gaf een foutwaarde 2 terug
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-image-generic:
 linux-image-generic is afhankelijk van linux-image-extra-3.13.0-35-generic; maar:
  Pakket linux-image-extra-3.13.0-35-generic is nog niet geconfigureerd.

dpkg: error processing package linux-image-generic (--configure):
 vereistenproblemen - blijft ongeconfigureerd
Er is geen apport-verslag weggeschreven omdat de foutmelding volgt op een eerdere mislukking.
          dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-generic:
 linux-generic is afhankelijk van linux-image-generic (= 3.13.0.35.42); maar:
  Pakket linux-image-generic is nog niet geconfigureerd.

dpkg: error processing package linux-generic (--configure):
 vereistenproblemen - blijft ongeconfigureerd
Er is geen apport-verslag weggeschreven omdat de foutmelding volgt op een eerdere mislukking.
              Instellen van google-chrome-beta (37.0.2062.94-1) ...
Instellen van openjdk-7-jre-headless:amd64 (7u65-2.5.1-4ubuntu1~0.14.04.1) ...
Installeren van nieuwe versie van configuratiebestand /etc/java-7-openjdk/sound.properties ...
Installeren van nieuwe versie van configuratiebestand /etc/java-7-openjdk/jvm-amd64.cfg ...
Instellen van openjdk-7-jre:amd64 (7u65-2.5.1-4ubuntu1~0.14.04.1) ...
Fouten gevonden tijdens behandelen van:
 linux-image-extra-3.13.0-35-generic
 linux-image-generic
 linux-generic
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Please copy the entire output of `apt-get dist-upgrade`, and add that [into your question](http://askubuntu.com/posts/513573/edit).

Comment: @saiarcot895 Done.

Comment: Oh, the problem is the boot space — had that before, know how to fix it, thanks!

Comment: Yeah, cleaning up the /boot space did, indeed, fix the problem. I didn't see the link as the first time I had this issue it was using the GUI software updater. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.
I had so space left at /boot, so I rm some old files and retry.

It works for me.